# ProQEXAFS: ImportError: cannot import name 'donaich' from 'lmfit.lineshapes'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, importerror

I'm trying to get the ProXAS_v2.43 running for the evaluation of QEXAFS data. I installed the necessary packages the manual provided, but when I try to start the program I get the following error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'donaich' from 'lmfit.lineshapes' (C:\Users\sq0346\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\lineshapes.py)**

All packages required listed by **conda search**  , should be present.
Mainly: Pandas, Scipy, Numpy-indexed, Xraylarch

Full error:

> File
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Lib\site-packages\ProQEXAFS-GUI-master\ProXAS-2.43\ProXAS_v2.43.py:9
> in 
> import tkinter, time, os, psutil, subprocess, sys, shutil, ast, codecs, re, larch, gc, peakutils.peak, itertools
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch_*init*_.py:47 in 
> from . import builtins
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch\builtins.py:21 in 
> from . import math
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch\math_*init*_.py:4 in
>
> from .utils import (linregress, realimag, as_ndarray,
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch\math\utils.py:11 in
>
> from .lineshapes import gaussian, lorentzian, voigt
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch\math\lineshapes.py:16 in
>
> from lmfit.lineshapes import (gaussian, lorentzian, voigt, pvoigt, moffat,
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'donaich' from 'lmfit.lineshapes'
> (C:\Users\sq0346\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\lineshapes.py)

Updating XRaylrach to version 0.9.60 resolved it, but produced a new error:

> File
> ~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ProQEXAFS-GUI-master\ProXAS-2.43\ProXAS_v2.43.py:9
> in 
> import tkinter, time, os, psutil, subprocess, sys, shutil, ast, codecs, re, larch, gc, peakutils.peak, itertools
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch_*init*_.py:48 in 
> from .version import **date**, **version**, **release_version**
>
> ImportError: cannot import name '**release_version**' from
> 'larch.version'
> (C:\Users\sq0346\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\larch\version.py)

Comment: Please update the description and tags to indicate what library you are trying to use. I assume it's called ProQEXAFS or something similar? This will direct your question to the appropriate group of users instead of the general python community.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update xraylarch to its latest version.  That will fix the misspelled import.